# how to disable sorting and filtering for specific columns in aggrid

Tags: typescript, angular8, ag-grid

I want to disable sorting and filtering for specific columns in ag-grid.

Code that i have :

```
const columnDefs: any =
      [
        {
          headerName: "Name", field: "name", sort: 'asc'
        },
        { headerName: "Age", field: "age" },
        {
          headerName: "Active", field: "isActive", cellRendererFramework: MyCheckboxComponent
        }

];

this.gridOptions = {
      columnDefs: columnDefs,
      enableSorting: true,
      enableFilter: true,
}
```

In this i want to disable sorting for active column. I tried the below code but it didnt help.

```
headerName: "Active", field: "isActive",enableSorting:false,enableFilter:false, cellRendererFramework: MyCheckboxComponent
```

but the above code didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Got it solved by adding `suppressMenu: true,suppressSorting: true,` which solved my issue. Thanks